# preg_match function not working with slashes

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a function that compares 2 strings. It works perfectly except when the string contains a slash `/`. What can I do to fix this?

```
function in_array_r($item , $array){
    return preg_match('/"'. preg_quote($item, "/") .'"/i' , json_encode($array));
}
```

I run it like:

```
if(in_array_r($row['name'], $products)){
    //
}
```

So `silverware with golden spoon new` works while `silverware with golden spoon / new` does not because of the slash even if it exists in both arrays.

Comment: Have you dumped the regex and looked at it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You mean compare the 2 arrays? The contents of both are pretty much the same. I've looked at them.

Comment: No, I mean the return value of `preg_quote`. You need to make sure that it contains expected value. Also dump the json encoded array. Visit then regex101.com and use both to verify that the regex is working

Comment: Thanks, will try that! :)

Comment: What is within your `$item`

Comment: `$item` is basically the name of the product, so `silverware with golden spoon / new` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to use escape character like this:

```
silverware with golden spoon \/ new
```

This will skip any character after the \ sign.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of two things to solve your problem here.

First, if you know that you are going to have slashes occurring frequently in your data, you should choose a different delimiter.  I generally use tildes instead of forward slashes because I parse a lot of URLs and I got tired of having to worry about escaping them all of the time.

The second thing I would do is to use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag with your `json_encode`.  Here's an example of what I mean:

```
<?php

$products = array('silverware with golden spoon new', 'silverware with golden spoon / new');

$item = 'silverware with golden spoon / new';

function in_array_r($item , $array){
    return preg_match('~"'.$item.'"~i', json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
}


if(in_array_r($item, $products)){
    print "Match found!";
}
else {
    print "No match was found.";
}
```

This will output:

```
Match found!
```

Here is a working demo:

http://ideone.com/BLEsIy